# C++ template specialization for pointer?

Tags: c++, templates

I read book < C++ Templates - the Complete Guide > and learned template specialization for pointer. (maybe I misunderstand this part of the book)

(1) Here's my simple template:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void Function(const T& a)
{
    std::cout << "Function<T>: " << a << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void Function<T*>(const T* a)
{
    std::cout << "Function<T*>: " << a << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    Function(1);
    Function(1.2);
    Function("hello");
    Function((void*)0x25);

    return 0;
}
```

I use ubuntu16.04 x64, g++ 5.3, the compiler report:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.exe 
main.cpp:10:29: error: non-type partial specialization ‘Function<T*>’ is not allowed
 void Function<T*>(const T* a)
```

(2) but this code is correct:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void Function(const T& a)
{
    std::cout << "Function<T>: " << a << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    Function(1);
    Function(1.2);
    Function("hello");
    Function((void*)0x25);

    return 0;
}
```

result shows:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.exe
$ ./main.exe 
Function<T>: 1
Function<T>: 1.2
Function<T>: hello
Function<T>: 0x25
```

My question is: Is the book about pointer specialization is wrong ? Or I mis understand the meaning of this part in the book ? Or something else ?

Update about pointer specialization in class.

(3) template class with pointer specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Base {
    T member;

    Base(const T& a)
        : member(a)
    {
    }

    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << member << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Base<T*> {
    T* member;

    Base(T* a)
        : member(a)
    {
    }

    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << member << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Base<int> b1(12);
    Base<double> b2(2.4);
    Base<char*> b3("hello");
    Base<void*> b4((void*)0x25);

    b1.hello();
    b2.hello();
    b3.hello();
    b4.hello();

    return 0;
}
```

this code is correct with one warning:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.exe 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:37:27: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     Base<char*> b3("hello");
                           ^
$ ./main.exe 
12
2.4
hello
0x25
```

(4) template class without pointer specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Base {
    T member;

    Base(const T& a)
        : member(a)
    {
    }

    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << member << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Base<int> b1(12);
    Base<double> b2(2.4);
    Base<char*> b3("hello");
    Base<void*> b4((void*)0x25);

    b1.hello();
    b2.hello();
    b3.hello();
    b4.hello();

    return 0;
}
```

result is the same:

```
$ g++ main.cpp -o main.exe
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:39:27: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
     Base<char*> b3("hello");
                           ^
$ ./main.exe 
12
2.4
hello
0x25
```

Does this means pointer specialization is needless ?
Or maybe this feature behave differently on different compiler ?

Comment: What is Test? It's not used anywhere? Why is the same function declared twice? What is the compiler error? Please post just the relevant code.

Comment: Usually the answer is in the error message. Did you take a look at it?

Comment: The error I get with clang is `error: function template partial specialization is not allowed`. GCC reports similar. That should answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message told you what is wrong:

> ```
> non-type partial specialization ‘Function<T*>’ is not allowed
> ```

You can only partially specialize types (classes). You've tried to partially specialize a function. Functions are not types; you can only fully specialize them.

Comment: Oh yes, My mistake.

Answer (score 9):

as you've been already told, partial specialization of function templates are not allowed. You can use `std::enable_if` for this:

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = 0>
void func(T val) { std::cout << val << std::endl; }

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value>* = 0>
void func(T val) { func(*val); }
```

If you are looking for simpler syntax, wait for concepts

Comment: How would you do it with concepts?

Comment: @Teharez like this:
`template <typename T>
requires !std::is_pointer_v<T>
void func(T val) { std::cout << val << std::endl; }`
and second overload accordingly. You can also put `requires` as function qualifier or use some concept for pointer

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. You are not allowed to partially specialise a function.
2. The behaviour of `(void*)0x25` is *undefined*. With the exception of `nullptr`, you are not allowed to set a pointer to memory you don't own, with the exception of one past the final element of an array and one past the address of a scalar.

Comment: the (void*)0x25 is not from the book, it's my mistake.