# How do I return a copy of a member variable in a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Template newbie here. I'm playing with the following test class:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:

    Container(T t) : m_t(t) {}

    T clone()
    {
        return m_t;
    }

private:

    T m_t;
};
```

The `clone()` method returns a copy of the member variable. Obviously, this doesn't work as intended if T is a pointer, e.g.:

```
Container<SomeClass*> container(new SomeClass());
```

The `clone()` method would simply return a pointer and not a full clone. I'm aware of the beauty of `if constexpr` but unfortunately I'm stuck with a C++14 compiler. I would like to keep my class generic so that it would also work with pointers. Should I create two different methods? Can SFINAE be of any help here?

Comment: Just to clarify. Are you expecting a deep copy, if you have a pointer?

Comment: For the first glance, a specialization for pointers should solve your problem. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737752/c-template-specialization-for-pointer) for an example. Finally, in the `clone()` member function just return the dereferenced member pointer as a copy. (It's up to you whether you expect a pointer in the constructor or a constant reference, or maybe a copy.)

Comment: @ArminMontigny  the T copy constructor should get called. Something like `return new T(*m_t)` ...

Comment: Why are you dealing with `new` & `delete` directly to begin with? I'd rather use smart pointers...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I know, this is for educational purposes

Comment: Actually doing a copy might not be the best design decision, though. Note all the standard containers don't do this sort of thing: like `std::vector<SomeClass*>` will just treat its elements as simple copyable pointers, and the code using the `vector` is responsible for worrying about object lifetimes etc. Also, if `SomeClass` is a polymorphic base class and an element actually has a derived type, the copy would fail to compile if `SomeClass` is abstract or slice the object if it is not abstract.

Comment: Who is responsible for deleting the newly created object at construction? And when you  make a copy? Such design make it easy to have memory leak...

Comment: @Phil1970, I'm aware the best way is to use smart pointers. I'm just trying to wrap my head around the template philosophy :)

Comment: Another problem with that code is that you have to ensure that the object is of type T and not a derived class. Otherwise, you will get object slicing.

Comment: Also that would not deal with deep copy vs shallow copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To specialize the entire class, as the other answer suggests, you might need to duplicate a lot of code (not a good thing).

Instead, I'd suggest good ol' *tag dispatch*:

```
template<typename T>
class Container
{
    T clone_low(std::false_type)
    {
        return m_t;
    }

    T clone_low(std::true_type)
    {
        return new std::remove_pointer_t<T>(m_t);
    }

  public:
    Container(T t) : m_t(t) {}

    T clone()
    {
        return clone_low(std::is_pointer<T>{});
    }

  private:
    T m_t;
};
```

Comment: Looks good, as it prevents code duplication. However the second `clone_low` triggers a compiler error: `error: cannot convert ‘T**’ to ‘T*’ in return`. Return type should be `T*` instead of `T` I guess...

Comment: As written, your copy constructor would get a pointer instead of a reference (as usually expected)

Comment: @Phil1970 Do you mean the `Container(T t)` constructor? That seems to be what OP wants (the question mentions this usage: `Container<SomeClass*> container(new SomeClass());`).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *partial specialization* of the class. For example

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Container
{
public:
    Container(T t) : m_t(t) {}
    T clone()
    {
        return m_t;
    }

private:

    T m_t;
};

template<typename T>
class Container<T*>
{
public:
    Container(T* t) : m_t(new T(*t)) {}
    T* clone()
    {
        return new T(*m_t);
    }
    ~Container() { delete m_t; }

private:
    T* m_t;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Container<int>(10).clone() << '\n';

    int x = 20;
    Container<int*> c(&x);

    int* p = c.clone();
    std::cout << *p << '\n';

    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While adequate for educational purpose, I would not recommand that in production code as it is somewhat error prone to memory leak, object slicing or double delete if not used properly. This can cause hard to find bugs.