# How can I write a version of a function to take pointer types?

Tags: c++, overloading

std::to_string doesn't take the all the types I want, and so I have my own functions. But I'm having trouble creating a string from pointer types. In the following code I want the two calls in main() to call the (const void*) versions of toString():

```
std::string toString(const void* arg)
{
    return std::to_string((unsigned long long) arg);
}

template <typename T>
std::string toString(T arg)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>); // Do something
    // Else do something else

    return std::string();
}

struct Bar {};

int main()
{
    // I want pointer types to call the pointer version of the function (const void*)
    Bar* bar = 0;
    Bar** bar2 = 0;
    toString(bar);
    toString(bar2);

}
```

The basic idea is that I want pointer values (no matter what they're pointing to) converted to string.

Comment: "having trouble" is not a problem description. What happens when this code is run? Why is that wrong?

Comment: Anyway, I presume it's that C++ lacks implicit conversion to `void*`, and that's _good_. What you probably want is a template function, constrained by [`std::is_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer).

Comment: @underscore_d How is it that std::cout << anypointer; works? That is basically what I want, give it a pointer to anything and then convert to a string. I looked Visual Studio implementation of std::cout and it seems it calls a function taking a const void*, that's why I imitated that.

Comment: Library implementation details are not a good reference point for how to write good end-user code. It doesn't make sense to feel you have to copy that one. It is safer and more self-documenting to write a template function that only accepts pointer types and converts them all to `std::uintptr_t` and prints that.

Comment: You can try to partially specialize your function for pointers using [enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41738326/199421)

Answer (score 1):

You already use `if constexpr`, so you might do

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString(T arg)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>) {
        return std::to_string((unsigned long long) arg);
    } else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>) {
        // Do something
        return std::string();
    } else {
        // Else do something else
        return std::string();
    }
}
```